# Laravel many layer eloquent relationship

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have following eloquent.

Volume,
Issue,
Category,
Article,
ArticleTranslation,

Volume can have many issues.
Issue can have many categories.
Category can have many articles.
Article can have many translation.

SO how  can i get Volume from Article/ArticleTranslation?

Comment: 4 levels in a database will result in poor performance and lots of unnecessary overhead. Consider **denormalizing** your tables.

Comment: @Mysteryos thanks for your suggestion, I go with denormalizing the tables.

Answer (score 1):

First your models.

```
..
class Volume extends Model {
  public function issues() {
    return $this->hasMany(Issue::class);
  }
}

class Issue extends Model {
  public function volume() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Volume::class);
  }
  public function categories() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
  }
}

class Category extends Model {
  public function issue() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Issue::class);
  }
  public function articles() {
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
  }
  public function articlesTranslated() {
    return $this->hasMany(ArticleTranslated::class);
  }
}

class Article extends Model {
  public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
  }
}
..
```

Then in your code:

```
..
$articles = Articles::all();
$volumes = [];
foreach ($articles as $article) {
  $volumes[] = $article->category->issue->volume;
}
..
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Comment: Some `eager-loading` would help the query's performance. `Articles::with('category.issue.volume')->get()`

Comment: @Damain your solution will cause the N + 1 problem. For every loop a new query will be execute which will cause a big performance issue. Use eager loading instead.